# How to assert that a function call does not return an error with unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

Is there anyway with unittest to just assert that a function call does not result in an error, whether it is a TypeError, IOError, etc.

example:

```
assert function(a,b) is not error
```

or

```
if not assertRaises function(a, b)
```

What is the best way to do this (without using classes)?  The trouble I'm having is all the useful documentation I come a cross in unittest is all class based and I don't want to use class based.

Full example:

```
def test_validate_params():
    assert test.validate_params('hackenv-re', 'test.username') is not errors
    assert test.validate_params('fakeenv', 'test.username') is error
    assert test.validate_params('hackevn-re', 'vagrant') is error
    counter += 1
    print "Test Passed {0}/5: validate_params".format(counter)
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code you want to test. Depending on how your method looks like, there are different ways to do this.

Comment: I have everything in place, I'm just trying to adjust the lines I have pasted in the example.  It's just a function call test(a,b)

Comment: It's hard to determine the best approach without at least getting a look at how you are testing. For example here. If I am going to test that it did not raise, I'm going to make sure that code returns "stuff". That way I know it did not assert.

Comment: Oh I see, I have updated the post

Answer (score 1):

If your function raises an exception, the test will fail. There is no need to do any additional checks. If you absolutely want to, you can do something like this:

```
try:
    function_under_test()
except Exception as e:
    self.fail("Unexpected exception %s" % e)
```

(assuming standard Python unittest)