# How to assert that an error is not raised with python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

So I am trying to import a module, and test methods from a class in that module.

Here is an example of a method.

```
def production_warning(self, targetenv):
    if targetenv == 'prdv':
        prodwarning1 = raw_input("WARNING: You are deploying to the production environment.  Are you sure you want to do this?   Y/N:  ").upper()
        if prodwarning1 == "N":
            sys.exit()
        prodwarning2 = raw_input("DEPLOYING TO PRDV, ARE YOU REALLY, REALLY SURE?  Y/N:  ").upper()
        if prodwarning2 == "N":
            sys.exit()
    else:
        return True
```

Here is an example of a test I am trying to write.

```
def production_warning():
    try:
        assert test.production_warning('prdv') is not errors
        assert test.validate_params('fakeenv') is errors
        print "Test Passed {0}/5: validate_params".format(counter)
        test_db_refresh()
    except:
        print "Test Failed {0}/5: validate_params".format(counter)
        test_db_refresh()

def db_refresh_prompt():
    # assert test.db_refresh_prompt() is not errors
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print "Test Passed {0}/5: db_refresh_prompt".format(counter)

production_warning()
db_refresh_prompt()
etc()
```

How do I check if an error is raised?  At the end of the day I'm trying to run through all of these tests and for each function, if no exceptions are raised, print "Success".  If an exception is raised, move on to the next test.  People seem to keep pointing me in the direction of "calling your function will automatically raise an exception if there is one", but this will stop my test whenever an exception is thrown and I don't want that, I want to continue on to the next test.

I can work around this by doing:

```
def validate_params():
try:
    assert test.validate_params('hackenv-re', 'test.username') is not errors
    assert test.validate_params('fakeenv', 'test.username') is errors
    assert test.validate_params('hackevn-re', 'vagrant') is errors
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print "Test Passed {0}/5: validate_params".format(counter)
    test_db_refresh()
except:
    print "Test Failed {0}/5: validate_params".format(counter)
    test_db_refresh()
```

but it seems like that defeats the purpose of using unittest in the first place?  I thought with unittest I can just assert if an exception is raised and it returns a T/F that I can do whatever I want with.

Hope that is enough information.

Based on many of the answers given, I'm assuming there is nothing built in to unittest where I can do assertRaise (I believe this is used in Django)

Comment: So are you using unittest or not? Your code doesn't look like you are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assert that a function call does not return an error with unittest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142282/how-to-assert-that-a-function-call-does-not-return-an-error-with-unittest)

Comment: All I'm trying to do is use unittest and find a way to test if an exception is raised.  That's it.  How do I check if an exception is raised?

Comment: What do you want to use from unittest if it's not classes? Everything in unittest is classes. You just want to import unittest and then forget about it?

Comment: So I cannot use unittest without using the class ?

Comment: I updated my post but, it sounds like I need to rewrite everything inside a class first so that I can actually use unittest

Comment: So I think in the very last example I pasted, if I just remove 'assert' and 'is not errors', this will accomplish what I am trying to do..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a Python unittest if an exception isn't raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181555/pass-a-python-unittest-if-an-exception-isnt-raised)

Answer (score 8):

Asserting that the tested code does not raise exceptions comes for free, you don't need to write code for that.

Comment: If I have 5 functions similar to production_warning that run tests, and I want to run all 5 in one pass, an exception will cause the whole thing to stop.

Comment: Any failed assertion would cause the whole thing to stop. So you don't want to assert after all?

Comment: ohhhh, I guess not.  I don't want it to stop.

Comment: Any failed assertion would cause the whole thing to stop unless you wrap it in a try - except clause.

Comment: This answer is wrong. An error is conceptually different from a failure. I don't want the test to throw an error if the thing that is tested throws an error, I want the test to fail. Whoever claims "Asserting that the tested code does not raise exceptions comes for free" doesn't fully understand the concept of testing

Comment: @Alex The standard way for a python test to fail is raising an exception. That's how the test runner knows that the test failed. Of course you could implement some concept of failure without raising and then write a custom test runner that can detect such failures. But I don't think that's what's being asked here.